# Embed widget using iframe in piwik v2.16

Tags: matomo

I am using piwik v2.16, and scared of upgrading this to v3.0 right now. I see a lot of old posts regarding this embed functionality so I believe this may not be exclusinve for v3.0.But unfortunately, I do not see an option to get the embed link for my widgets. I have enabled the Annonymous user view access and try to follow the article here:

> https://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/#embed-a-piwik-report-in-a-html-page

, but not sure why I do not have option to get embed link. I can see other options like export as image, csv etc.

Can any one please help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the embed link go to the admin settings and then select Widgets in the sidebar.